# How to asociate appsettings.json with a class and Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an API .NET 5 proyect and I have another proyect (library) that is reference from the API.

I have this appsettings.json in the API project:

```
 {
  "ConfigurationSettings": {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "connStringDefault",
      "Other": "connStringOther"
    }
  }
}
```

And this class in the library:

```
public class ConfigurationSettings
{
    public ConnectionStrings ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
}

public class ConnectionStrings
{
    public string DefaultConnection { get; set; }

    public string Other { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use this class to search in the appsettings.json, like this:

```
string ConnString = ConfigurationSettings.ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection;
```

But I need this to be with dependency injection, to use like this:

```
 private readonly IEmpleadoRepository _empleadoRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IConfigurationSettings _config;


    public GetEmpleadoByIdHandler(IEmpleadoRepository empleadoRepository, IMapper mapper, IConfigurationSettings config)
    {
        _empleadoRepository = empleadoRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _config = config;
    }
```

I google it and I cannot find the correct steps.

Comment: Maybe you can try using `IConfiguration` that you already get for free? (`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions`)  And you can map your custom `ConfigurationSettings` section.

Comment: With this: (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions) and this other (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder), I resolve this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Want do you need is called an options pattern. [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

To use this first of all you need to create a binding between your class and your config file. Add this code into your startup class.

```
services.AddOptions<ConfigurationSettings>();
```

After it, you can use this in DI.

```
private readonly IEmpleadoRepository _empleadoRepository;
private readonly IMapper _mapper;
private readonly ConfigurationSettings _config;


public GetEmpleadoByIdHandler(IEmpleadoRepository empleadoRepository, 
IMapper mapper, 
IOptions<ConfigurationSettings> options)
{
    _empleadoRepository = empleadoRepository;
    _mapper = mapper;
    _config = options.Value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With this nuget:

(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions)

and this other:

(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder)

You can inject dependency like this:

```
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;


    public GetEmpleadoByIdHandler(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
```

then you can do this:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
            _config.Bind("ConfigurationSettings", config);

            string conn = config.ConnectionStrings.MongoDB;
```