# How can I read particular data structure from appSettings.json?

Tags: c#, json, data-structures, appsettings

I've the follow data structure in my appSettings.json.

```
"Ranges": [
  {
    "K": 1,
    "Min": 2,
    "Max": 3
  },
  {
    "K": 2,
    "Min": 4,
    "Max": 6
  }
]
```

What is data structure should I use in my C# code for reading that? I know that I can't use cortage, in this case I would be use the follow code:

```
class RangeOptions
{
   public List<(int K, int Min, int Max)> Ranges {get;set;} //What should I use into List<?>
}
```

But as I know, it doesn't fit for reading this structure. Could you help me with my issue please?

Thank you, guys!

Comment: Create a class with `K`, `Min` and `Max` properties. and do `List<theclassname>`

Comment: Oh, that's all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to asociate appsettings.json with a class and Dependency Injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70028185/how-to-asociate-appsettings-json-with-a-class-and-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var section = configuration.GetSection("Ranges");
var Ranges= section.Get<List<Range>>();
```

Class

```
Class Public Range
{
 public int K {get;set;}
 public int Min {get;set;}
 public int Max {get;set;}
}
```

Or By `Linq`

```
var desire = configuration
   .GetSection("Ranges")
   .GetChildren()
   .Select(x => x.yourvalue);
```